# Get an iframe to ignore other content

Tags: html, css, iframe

*There's probably an answer to this one, but despite 20 minutes of searching I can't find it.*

I have an `<iframe>` (Embedded Google Maps) which I want to put on the right side of my content div, but it keeps on interfering with the text in the box. It won't allow me to put the text and the iframe side-by-side (but insists on putting one on top of the other).

I've tried multiple varieties of text-align, float and clear. Absolute position sort-of right thing, but leaves the box misshaped and I don't think it is the 'right' way to do it.

As for code, there's not much:

```
<div>
<iframe>
<h1>Header</h1>
Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

**First one happens, should be like the second one:**

[image]

Comment: Provide example code, ideally which demonstrates the exact problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float them side by side in container-type boxes

```
.inner-box {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Have a look at this Fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/wyj5tb22/2/